# Positioning a 16x9 image in the upper side of the app window (constraints layout) (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

I have some 16x9 images which I want to use them like there are the cover images from facebook.
something like this:

[image]

the idea is that i want it to be fixed in the upper part without changing its ratio

I tried this using constraint layuout but depending on the screen width it changes the size and ratio.
I will also want to add some text and one more picture over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"` so the height will be adjusted according to the width , so when the screen width changes from device to other the the height will always be 9 ratio form the width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cover"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9" /> 
<!-- here you can add other views below -->
<TextView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cover"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you !
I also needed   android:scaleType="centerCrop" so the image fits the view